# Necessary Condition For Having A Normal Subgroup Of A Non Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there any necessary condition for non abelian group to have a normal subgroup?

Comment: Do you have any specific conditions in mind that you're hoping for?

Comment: The negation of any item listed in http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Simple_group#Weaker_properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking a very general question; i.e., what implications occur when a non-abelian group is not simple (aka, has a proper normal subgroup). In response, here's a general fact: if the group is finite, [its order must be even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem).